# hibernate SELECT causes UPDATE

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, sybase

This question is similar to the following:

[What caused hibernate generate a update clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514916/what-caused-hibernate-generate-a-update-clause)

But it seems to not have answer

The log says the following is the update message. We are not explicitly doing this, however. Hibernate is somehow auto generating this upon a SELECT statement

```
update
        ops2.dbo.ObjectA
    set
        AcceptDate=?,
        ActionTaken=?,
        ModifyBy=?,
        ModifyByID=?,
        ModifyDate=?,
        ModifyDept=?,
        ParentId=?,
        Priority=?,
        RepRqmt=?,
        SchedDate=?,
        SchedDate=?,      
    where
        Rank=?
```

This is the statement that generates the problem:

```
  Query query =
            session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM ProductOrders").addEntity(MyOrder.class);

        List<MyOrder> orders= query.list();
```

Comment: how do you create your session? what flush strategy you are using? do you maybe read an instance of ObjectA then modify some fields of it while it's still attached to the session? that unaccepted answer can also give you some clues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Hibernate flushes the pending changes before executing a query, to make sure that the query sees the changes that you've made before executing this query. If it didn't you could have this frustrating situation:

```
Foo foo = (Foo) session.get(Foo.class, 1L);
foo.setColor("red");
List<Foo> redFoos = 
    session.createQuery("select foo from Foo foo where foo.color = 'red'");
if (redFoos.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("WTF?");
}
```